# Find duplicates in dataframe by compound criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe which has data like:

```
col1    col2    col3
1       3       bob
2       1       alice
3       3       bob
4       3       rose
```

And what I want to do is keep duplicate rows of col2 and discard duplicates with greater than 1 instance of col3's value. Or put another way, duplicates of col2 but only where col3's values are different. So in the above example, what I would end up with is:

```
col1    col2    col3
1       3       bob
4       3       rose
```

Alice wouldn't be in the output because obviously there's no second value of col2's '1' - it isn't duplicate. The second entry of Bob (3  3   bob) wouldn't be in the output because while col2's '3' is a duplicate, col3's 'bob' is already in the result set (1  3  bob). (I am aware of the `keep=` parameter to change the behaviour of keeping first or last, but ignoring it for simplicity.)

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  a combination of `.duplicated()`, `.drop_duplicates()` and the `loc` accessor

```
df.loc[df[df['col2'].duplicated(False)].col3.drop_duplicates(keep='first').index,:]



 col1  col2  col3
0     1     3   bob
3     4     3  rose
```

**How it works**

```
#Filter all duplicated in col2 using duplicated(False)

df[df['col2'].duplicated(False)]



#Drop duplicates in col3 but retaining first using .drop_duplicates(keep='first')

df[df['col2'].duplicated(False)].col3.drop_duplicates(keep='first')



#Extract index

df[df['col2'].duplicated(False)].col3.drop_duplicates(keep='first').index



#Finally filter using loc accessor
     df.loc[index,all columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the False in duplicated for the `keep=` arg? Also, how can I escape a hyphen in `col3` string?

Comment: From documentation, `duplicated(False); marks all duplicates as True` which means it makes them boolean allowing filtration.Not sure which hyphen you are talking about. Please explain

Comment: Ah, yes. If `col3` was string `col-3` instead how do you escape the hyphen in the `.<col_name>.drop_duplicates...` access

Comment: `df['col_name'].drop_duplicates` should do if I get you clearly. If not explain further

Comment: The one-liner doesn't work for me. I need to split it into chained commands because of non-alphanumeric character in col3 name, so I can't access it as you have done.

Comment: It should work. It worked on your sample dateset. Can you provide more data to see why it is failing. What version of pandas are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.loc[df.drop_duplicates(['col2', 'col3'])
         .duplicated(['col2'], keep=False).loc[lambda x: x].index]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3   bob
3     4     3  rose
```

Details:

Inside df.loc find indexes using

- first `drop_duplicates` to get rid of duplicate records of col2 and
  col3
- use `duplicated` with `keep = False` return True for all records with
  duplicate 'col2'
- lastly, use `loc` with lambda to boolean select only those True
  indexes